# How to communicate with android smartphone as BLE Gatt-Server from universal windows BLE Gatt-client?

Tags: c#, android, uwp, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently under Windows 10 it is not possible to connect to BLE device without pairing manually first. The devices that I want to handle as a server (peripheral in BLE communication concept) is android smartphone with OS version 5 and Bluetooth version 4.
I'm using two following samples, one for android gatt-server and another as UWP Gatt-client app.
https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLEClient

I have two problems about this issue. One is that, the client does not find the android-server for paring and connecting, unless the server (smartphone) be paired with windows via Bluetooth Setting App. The second problem is that after the paring although the client can see the server but I cannot connect to that, at this time I have an error on this line.

bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(rootPage.SelectedBleDeviceId);

Now how we can communicate with BLE android Gatt-Server through windows 10 universal apps as BLE Gatt-Client?

Comment: You can check the `Capabilities` in the `Package.appxmanifest` to ensure `Bluetooth` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This problem only occurs while I want to use Android smartphone as peripheral. As the Microsoft publisher says this sample (BluetoothLEClient) works correctly with heart rate sensors which act as peripheral. I guess this problem is related to Android peripheral sample, because due to the paring windows 10 is differ from android and ios in connecting to the peripheral device.